# mount dvd player

Tags: mount, dvd, devices

I just wanted to DVD player to view video and pictures on DVD and realized that I need mount the device to use it.

I want to learn the procedures to mount the device and to use it.
Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Iccsi,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the files on the DVD then try this:

1. You need to know the device name of the dvd player. This might be /dev/cdrom0. Otherwise you would have to check the folder /dev/. It could also be cdrom1, sr0, sr1.
2. You need a target folder to mount the dvd in. I would suggest the folder /mnt. But you need to check first if other things are mounted with /mnt. Type "mount" to check it.
3. Now we have a source and a destination. Use the command "sudo mount /dev/cdrom0 /mnt" (depending on your actual device name).
4. Now you can access the files. They wait for you on /mnt.

This will only be mounted temporary. As soon as you reboot it won't be mounted anymore.